# Ajax POST in Javascript - missing data

Tags: javascript, php, post

Here's what I'm trying to do:

I have a php script that needs geolocation data.  I execute a javascript on load to determine my coordinates and using ajax/jQuery I post those results (lat and long).

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'index.php',
    data: {
        lat: latitude,
        long: longitude
    },
    success: function( data ) {
       console.log( data );
    }
});
```

The script works, however, I am not getting the coordinates in the browser.  The javascript console shows the proper results.  Oddly enough, if I do:

```
$lat = $_POST['lat'];
$lon = $_POST['long'];

$handle = "/tmp/fish";
$mode = "w";
$fp = fopen($handle, $mode);
fwrite($fp,$lat);
fwrite($fp,',');
fwrite($fp,$lon);   
fclose($fp);
```

The file will have the correct coordinate results too.  If I do:

```
echo $_POST['lat'];
```

It will be empty. So I can get it to work by file I/O but I'd rather just handle it within the script.  After the above file I/O I have to execute a second php script via form action to open the file and get the data I need.
What am I missing?

Here's an example:
HTML:

```
print "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
print "</pre>";
    Array
    (
    )
```

Console:

```
<pre>Array
(
    [lat] => 40.####
    [long] => -82.####
)
</pre>
```

Entire javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function geoFindMe() {
  var output = document.getElementById("out");
  function success(position) {
    var latitude  = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;  

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'index.php',
        data: {
            lat: latitude,
            long: longitude
        },
        success: function( data ) {
           console.log( data );
           $("#lat").html(data['lat']);
           $("#long").html(data['long']);
           $("#lat").html("<b>" + data['lat'] + "</b>");

        }
    });
    function error() {
output.innerHTML = "Unable to retrieve your location";      
 }
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);

}

</script>
```

Now I've tried the suggestion of @Bradmage.  Code:

```
$lat = $_POST['lat'];
$lon = $_POST['long'];

$handle = "/tmp/fish";
$mode = "w";
$fp = fopen($handle, $mode);
fwrite($fp,$lat);
fwrite($fp,',');
fwrite($fp,$lon);   
fclose($fp);
cat fish
40.xxxxx,-82.xxxx
```

The data is in the file and I did my fclose.  Then:

```
$mode = "r";
$t = fopen($handle, $mode);
$r = fgetcsv($t, 1000, ",");
$r = print_array($r);
$lat = $r[0];
$long = $r[1];
```

$r[0] and $r[1] are empty.  If I make my form action another php script where I do the above read, I get the data.  I am totally stumped.

Comment: If your javascript console is showing you the proper values then your `echo` line is working as your ajax callback is logging the data echoed out by the script. Unless you are meaning you did a `console.log` somewhere else that you are not showing

Comment: I need that echo to show up in the body of my HTML and it is not.  The console shows my proper results regardless of whether I have that echo statement or not.  I was trying to show that I can get the results in the console but not get them to show up in the HTML stream.  FYI, I copied the javascript from someone else and know nothing about it.  My expertise lies in php.

Comment: So with the console.log(data) you do not see what is spit out from the php?

Comment: Do you think it would update the PHP that is all ready on the index page that is loaded? That code in the page that was loaded initially is already done.... it is not getting that data. Ajax call has nothing to do with that initial page load. If you want it to show up in the current page, than you are going to have to have the php code return the data and than you will need to display it with JavaScript.

Comment: Are you trying to echo things from index.php and expecting them to show up in the page itself instead of in the ajax response?  Your question is unclear and you provide an example like "Here's an example: HTML:" and then follow it with some php code.  Please clarify what you are doing, where you are doing it, what you are expecting and what actually happens.  Including the more of the relevant code will help.

Comment: Ok, the relevant code is up there aside from `<form action="index.php">` I'm expecting the JQuery/ajax code to update my $_POST but that may be a bad assumption.  So above I'm just trying to read my $_POST and lat and long are not there.

Comment: print_array isn't a PHP function. fgetcsv already returns an array so you can remove that line.

Comment: print_array is my UDF.  Sorry I didn't mention that.

Answer (score 0):

If your console is displaying the correct values, then they are being passed back correctly. What you need is more code to update your page.

Say you have to elements:

```
<div id="lat"></div>
<div id="long"></div>`
```

Under `console.log( data );` You need something like..

```
$("#lat").html(data['lat']);
$("#long").html(data['long']);
```

Then you can place the two divs wherever you want the numbers to appear on the page.

**edit**

In case your not familiar with jQuery, which I assume your using if you used .ajax, a couple jQuery basics.

$("") gets an object.

#lat is an elements ID.

.html() places html inside the element retrieved by $("#lat"). So you could use `$("#lat").html("<b>" + data['lat'] + "</b>");`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response.  When I use your code as instructed I get "undefined" in my div element. I'll edit to provide the entire js above.

Comment: Also just to clarify, I don't necessarily want to show it in a div element but I want my php code to be able to get ahold of it and stick it in a DB.

Comment: Ah Sorry I got the impression you 'didn't know how to modify the html elements. I think I understand now. What I don't get is why and where you are calling the second page from? Why can't you put the database code in the same page as $fp = fopen($handle, $mode); ?

Comment: This is all very strange to me.  I may need a better grasp of exactly how the code is run and perhaps a sequencing problem.  I tried your suggestion. Code added above for simplicity.

Comment: Back to basics. What are you trying to accomplish? Putting your location into a database? Page onload -> ajax(lat,long) -> add to database -> ajax response code(data). Is that about it?

Comment: Ok.  1) `<body onload="geoFindMe()">` in my header.  That script is pulled in via `include 'html.php'` which calls the loc.js script. 2) Collect additional data via a form. 3) write form data and geolocation to database.  This all works if I use a 2nd php script for my form action.  That script executes after I submit the form, I read my data from my file, get everything else from $_POST and execute my insert query.  The question here is why I need to maintain that second script and not being able to do it all in one php script?

Comment: I think your over complicating it. I'll post another answer, see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Very quick mockup. This will add the coordinates to your form, so you only need to submit it once with all your data in one form.

```
<head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var latitude  = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    $("#lat").val(latitude);
    $("#long").val(longitude);
});
</script>
</head>
<body onload="geoFindMe()">

<form action="..">
    <input type="text" name="var1">
    <input type="text" name="var2">
    <input type="hidden" id="lat" name="lat" />
    <input type="hidden" id="long" name="long" />

    <input type="submit" />
</form>

</body>
```

Now your script will have everything.

```
<?php
    $var1 = $_POST[...];
    $var2 = $_POST[...];
    $lat = $_POST['lat'];
    $lon = $_POST['long'];

    $handle = "/tmp/fish";
    $mode = "w";
    $fp = fopen($handle, $mode);
    fwrite($fp,$var1);
    fwrite($fp,',');
    fwrite($fp,$var2);
    fwrite($fp,',');
    fwrite($fp,$lat);
    fwrite($fp,',');
    fwrite($fp,$lon);   
    fclose($fp);
```